# Find and select a required word from a sentence?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get `raw_input` from user and then find a required word from that input. If the required word is there, then a function runs. So I tried `.split` to split the input but how do I find if the required word is in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple to get this done. Python has an `in` operator that does exactly what you need. You can see if a word is present in a string and then do whatever else you'd like to do.

```
sentence = 'hello world'
required_word = 'hello'

if required_word in sentence:
    # do whatever you'd like
```

You can see some basic examples of the `in` operator in action [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm).

Depending on the complexity of your input or lack of complexity of your required word, you may run into some problems. To deal with that you may want to be a little more specific with your required word.

Let's take this for example:

```
sentence = 'i am harrison'
required_word = 'is'
```

This example will evaluate to `True` if you were to do`if required_word in sentence:` because technically the letters `is` are a substring of the word "harrison".

To fix that you would just simply do this:

```
sentence = 'i am harrison'
required_word = ' is '
```

By putting the empty space before and after the word it will specifically look for occurrences of the required word as a separate word, and not as a part of a word.

**HOWEVER,** if you are okay with matching substrings as well as word occurrences then you can ignore what I previously explained.

> If there's a group of words and if any of them is the required one, then what should I do? Like, the required word is either "yes" or "yeah". And the input by user contains "yes" or "yeah".

As per this question, an implementation would look like this:

```
sentence = 'yes i like to code in python'
required_words = ['yes', 'yeah']
                  ^   ^  ^    ^
# add spaces before and after each word if you don't 
# want to accidentally run into a chance where either word 
# is a substring of one of the words in sentence

if any(word in sentence for word in required_words):
    # do whatever you'd like
```

This makes use of the `any` operator. The if statement will evaluate to true as long as at least one of the words in `required_words` is found in `sentence`.

Comment: I think the question is more looking for words than substrings

Comment: @cricket_007: No, I am satisfied with the answer as I am looking for just a substring.Anyway, I always like to accept more knowledge.

Comment: @Divyansh_C cricket was right in making sure I knew that you were looking for words and not substrings. Take a look at the example in my answer regarding `required_word = 'is'`. Unless you're okay with the expression evaluating to `True` in cases like that, you should definitely try and be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Harrison Oh now I understood the thing. Thank you! Also a thanks to cricket_007.

Comment: @Divyansh_C No problem, glad I could help! If you were completely satisfied by my response it would be awesome if you marked it as the answer :P

Comment: @Harrison If there's a group of words and if any of them is the required one, then what should I do? Like, the required word is either "yes" or "yeah". And the input by user contains "yes" or "yeah".

Comment: @Harrison Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Harrison's way is one way. Here are other ways:

Way 1:

```
sentence = raw_input("enter input:")
words = sentence.split(' ')
desired_word = 'test'

if desired_word in words:
    # do required operations
```

Way 2:

```
import re

sentence = raw_input("enter input:")
desired_word = 'test'
if re.search('\s' + desired_word + '\s', sentence.strip()):
    # do required operations
```

Way 3 (especially if there are punctuations at the end of the word):

```
import re

sentence = raw_input("enter input:")
desired_word = 'test'
if re.search('\s' + desired_word + '[\s,:;]', sentence.strip()):
    # do required operations
```